# Moving specific values into same values column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

> I am trying to separate the values and sort them into another df
> with numerical values.
> If any values appear in the ID it will appear as 1 in the new df and 0 if the value is not present.

```
ID   Values
0    1,2,3  
1    2,5,7,8
2    4,5,10

Results

ID 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
0  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1  0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
2  0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: `df[['ID']].join(df['Values'].str.get_dummies(','))`

Answer (score 2):

After `get_dummies` we still need reindex to get back those missing column

```
s = df.join(df.pop('Values').str.get_dummies(',')).set_index('ID')
s.columns = s.columns.astype(int)
s = s.reindex(columns = range(1, s.columns.max()+1),fill_value=0)
s
Out[61]: 
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
ID                                        
0    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1    0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
2    0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the `Values` column to tuple format using `eval` and then use the [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) method to get the expected result:

```py
>>> df['Values'] = df['Values'].apply(eval)
>>> pd.get_dummies(df['Values'].apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int)).sum(level=0)
    1   2   3   4   5   7   8   10
0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0
2   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
```